# Query XML Data in SQLite

Tags: xml, sqlite, parsing, types

I have a column in a table that holds XML and I want to parse the XML using a query ... is this possible in SQLite?

I was going to try to write my own XML parser but read that SQLite doesn't support loops so not sure how I would do that considering I am doing it in SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cursor to retrieve data from sqllite and parse the XML. You can use XmlPullParser to parse the XML.